# Typescript outFile, Angular2 and Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, systemjs

**tsconfig.json**

```
{  
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"module": "system",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"sourceMap": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"lib": [ "dom", "es6" ],
"noImplicitAny": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"outFile": "tsbundle.js"
},
"compileOnSave": true
}
```

I manually include tsbundle.js to my html page.

I've got an angular module, called NavigationModule which is @NgModule and its main.ts looks like this:

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { NavigationModule } from './navigation.module';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(NavigationModule);
```

My question is: how to configure systemjs.config.js

Current setup (not working)

**systemjs.config.js**

```
packages: {
        rxjs: {
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        Navigation: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            main: '/tsbundle.js'
        }
    }
```

I import the module like this:

index.html

```
System.import('Navigation/main').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
```

It still looks for the module not from the tsbundle.js, but from 
/en/Navigation/main.js (which of does not exist and fails)

How to tell it, that everything for the Navigation module is inside the tsbundle.js and it should download only that file.

Comment: I have this for the map:

'Navigation': '/tsbundle.js'

I don't have an 'app' property in map

Comment: give a try by doing `System.import('Navigation')` as you already mentioned `tsbundle.js` as `main`

Comment: if I do that, it tries to request:

/tsbundle.js//tsbundle.js which is not correct

Comment: isn't `main: '/tsbundle.js'` should be `main: './tsbundle.js'`

Comment: have you compiled your bundle in UMD format?

Comment: @pixelbits actually it is in system format as seen in the tsconfig above. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, never mind about UMD format - that applies to external modules that you've published for sharing (which is what I thought you were trying to do).  It seems you're loading your modules from a local TS file. You don't need a SystemJS configuration for TS files that you load locally